# VLOOKUP needs to find value from a list and if its equivalent then

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a problem where I'm currently using a `VLOOKUP` function on this sheet. [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BjB1kM3xVYQ8VEWYQvpGZhyDUrkR4yqCWtuQIxfJX-I/edit#gid=0)

What I wanted to happen is `VLOOKUP` would search on the List on G column and compare it to B column and if it matches. It will return a value `y`. The problem I encountered is it can't search from a list.

If anyone can help me. That would be great.

Comment: your sheet is private. share it or edit your question and add formula you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **`VLOOKUP`** should look something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B; List!G2:G; 1; 0); )<>""; "y"; ))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I found a solution earlier while waiting.